# How to write git commands to separate history file?

Tags: linux, bash, git, dotfiles

I'd like to stop `git` commands from writing to `$HISTFILE` and instead track them in their own file.

I expect all non-git commands to be written to `$HISTFILE` and all commands matching `"git*"` written to `~/.git_history`.

Comment: Do you also want to load that other file into your history? If you don't load the other file in newly opened shells then you have to re-type your git commands manually. In case you want to load the other file: What is the the order in which both history files should be merged?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you want to store the git commands in a separate file? Depending on your hidden goal there might be an easier solution.

Comment: Maybe you can do it by scrypting your HISTFILE like this : https://askubuntu.com/a/261667

Comment: @Socowi - If I misunderstood your questions please let me know. I do not want to load ".git_history" file into the shell when exec "history". I don't need them merged either. The end goal is to clean up my bash history while also keeping a log of my git commands. I could add "git*" to HISTIGNORE but I'm not sure how to also redirect that command to a different log file. The file ".git_history" should be sorted by most recent (similiar to .bash_history). 

I guess worst case scenario I could add a nightly cron to move "git*" from .bash_history to another file?

Comment: If you remove git commands from your shell history, you would no longer be able to press up to use them again.

Comment: @Socowi I smelling an XY problem.

Comment: Does it have to be in bash? zsh has a programmable line editor that could handle this, I believe. (If that's really what you want, I share the doubts of other commenters.)

Comment: @MichałPolitowski - Thank you, I'll look into it

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I am aware that it wont be available by pressing up on the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following function to your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_login` if you are using a Mac) and restart the terminal.

```
git() {
   fc -nl -0 | cut -c3- >> ~/.git_history
   history -d -1
   command git "$@"
}
```

When you use `git` in your shell this function will be called instead.

- The first line extracts your git command exactly how it would be stored to `.bash_history` (this includes unexpanded variables, quotes and so on) and appends it to `~/.git_history`.
- The second line deletes your git command from bash's regular history.
- The last line executes your git command as usual.

As discussed in the in the comments, `.git_history` will only serve as a log of entered git commands. You cannot use <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to get an entered git command back – not even in the same session.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an idea:

1. Use the `HISTIGNORE` shell variable to filter all `git` commands out of the normal command history.
2. Create a shell function called `git` that appends the line `git $@` to `~/.git_history` ... then executes `/usr/bin/git "$@"`.

But I don't think this is a good idea.  As @evolutionxbox points out, if you filter out all `git` commands you won't be able to do history completion for `git` commands.  (I would *hate* that ...)

And there is a significant flaw in this approach. Your fake git "history" file will only contain the command arguments for the `git` command after the shell has expanded them.  You won't record what was expanded, and you won't record any redirections or pipelines.

---

FWIW, I don't think that `bash` is capable of writing different parts of your history list to different files.  So the above may be as good as it gets ... unless you are prepared to modify `bash` itself.

Comment: Thank you. I'll play around with your answer and see if I can come up with a solution. I am pretty well versed in git so I find that having a bunch of git cmds cluttering up my history file is pointless. However, if something were to go horribly wrong, logging the cmds to a separate file would allow me to trace what I screwed up.

Comment: To get the unexpanded command you could setup a DEBUG trap and inspect `BASH_COMMAND`. If it starts with `git` then append it to `.git_history`.